# Package log4r-mongoDB integration

Tags: r, mongodb, logging, rmongodb, log4r

I explored the log4r package and found that we have console and file appenders. I am looking for pushing the logs to a mongoDB database. I am unable to find any way in pushing the logs to mongoDB, do we have any appender for the same.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoimport/) tool

If you do not specify a file (option `--file=`), mongoimport reads data from standard input (e.g. "stdin").

Or write logs into a temporary file and use mongoimport to import it.

Comment: Thank you . Let me try to work on this and get back in case of any issues.